# Missing: Utility Explorer in Management Studio 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, data-tier-applications

I am trying to use Data-Tier applications and am going through the tutorial [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633713(SQL.105).aspx).

When I get to step two the tutorial says to open Utility Explorer in the view menu. But it is not there! I looked all over the program for another entry point but I just dont see it.

I am currently running SQL Server 2008 R2 Version 10.50.1352.12 and I am connected to a server running SQL 2008 R2 Server Express.

Why cant I find it?

Comment: Is it the SQL Server 2008 R2 Server Express With Management Utilities though?

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the Express version of SQL Server Management Studio?  If so, that doesn't support the Utility Control Point stuff.  Also, you're connecting to SQL Server Express Edition, and that's not able to be a control point either.  You're in Enterprise territory.  You can use Developer Edition to play around, though, and it functions the same as Enterprise, except you're not allowed to use it for production.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're way past this but someone else might find it useful...?

I'm using 10.50.1600.1 and the utility is on the View menu of SSMS

But you don't have to "Configure the SQL Server Utility" - I have been using/deploying DAC packs pretty much since R2 RTMed and have bever used the utility.

Cheers

Mark

Answer (score 0):

Please verify that you installed SQL Server 2008 R2 - with "Management Tools - Complete" option

The steps to install are mentioned in the following link:
[SQL Server Management Studio Missing after 2008 R2 Install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957949/sql-server-management-studio-missing-after-2008-r2-install)

Hope this helps!