# SQL Server Management Studio Missing after 2008 R2 Install

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Just installed SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer Edition on my XP box. There is no sign of SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS). Aarg. And I can't seem to see that specific option available in Add Features. What do I do?

I did notice that my machine already had the setup files for SQL Server 2008 installed. So I uninstalled everything - first R2 then the setup for 2008, and now when I go to reinstall R2, still no option for SSMS in the feature list.

Help!

Comment: Did you search the hard drive for `ssms.exe`? Did you pick workstation components when you ran the install? Can you show a screen shot of the feature list so we know what you mean by "still no option"?

Comment: Do you have installation media? Just run it and click on Repair and follow the instructions. On "SQL Server Feature Installation" click next and select the tool that you would like to install.

Comment: @Krip, did you finally find this feature ? If not, i would recommend to install new instance.

Comment: Yep. The extract of ISO I used was missing files. So re extracted then installed and I had the option.

Comment: @Krip, in my original answer i have mentioned this " SQL Server 2008 Installation media, you can install just the Client/Workstation Components". Hope to get your vote. thanks

Answer (score 25):

You need to go to Control Panel, Add/Remove Features, pick SQL Server 2008 R2, and click Uninstall/Change.

It will ask you if you want to Add, Repair or Remove. Pick Add.

At this point you will have to point to the setup files. So if you have the DVD you will need to point the DVD drive, otherwise if you've mounted the ISO or have the installation files locally or on the network, you'll have to point to the folder that holds `setup.exe`. Once the installation files are recognized, you will:

- say OK on the "Setup Support Files" dialog
- click Next on the "Setup Support Rules" dialog
- choose "New Installation or Add Shared Features" on the "Installation Type" dialog and click Next
- click Next on the "Product Key" dialog (it should be pre-populated for you, or you may have to enter the product key if this is retail)
- accept the License Terms and click Next
- Setup Role should be "SQL Server Feature Installation" and click Next
- On the "Feature Selection" dialog, you should see options for "Management Tools - Basic" and "Management Tools - Complete" - make sure they both become checked, and click Next
- Click Next, Next, Next, Next, Install

Here is a screen shot of what the "Feature Selection" dialog should look like once you've checked "Management Tools - Basic" and "Management Tools - Complete":

[image: Feature Selection]

(If they're already checked, cancel and get out of setup - Management Studio is already installed.)

When installation has finished, you should find `ssms.exe` in the following location:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\
```

If you're on a 32-bit machine, I'm sorry. You'll have to look here instead:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\
```

Comment: I do NOT see Management Tools - that's the issue - it's a shortened list

Comment: @Krip can you show a screen shot and tell us exactly where you got the installer? You say it is Developer Edition but I suspect it's Express edition.

Comment: no, it is developer edition. ok, i think i found the problem - I re-extracted files from the ISO and this time got lots more files - so for some reason the WinZip extraction did not give me all files the first time

Answer (score 12):

In some cases the option is just not anywhere on the installation menu. Check my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834191/sql-server-management-studio-missing/11713463#11713463).

Basically just use the [Web Platform Installer 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) and get this: Products > Database > "Sql Server 2008 R2 Management Objects". Then "Management Tools" will be available, and follow previous answers.